# Android Device Editor doesn't let choose view

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

I have added 3 layout land folders in my /res dirctory:

- layout-land-hdpi
- layout-w420dp-land
- layout-w560dp-land

Now I can't choose 420dpi device from editor, or hdpi device because it will always redirect me to w560dp xml file (hdpi can be chosen for watches tho):

https://pasteboard.co/GXDlvF7.png

Comment: for me, i close android studio and delete manualy ;)

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean, my problem is that I cant have preview for intended screen size